# Generating HTML from non-MVC class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a method that grabs the localization of a given string and returns it. This method is called by an extension method of `HtmlHelper`, so that it is accessible from Razor views. However, sometimes we also use it in controllers and other non-Razor places, and that's why we have the "inner" method.

Now, for debug purposes, I'd like to wrap the returned, localized (or maybe not) string into some HTML (something like `<span class="localized">Returned text</span>`). However, if I write

```
return string.Format("<span class=\"localized\">{0}</span>", text);
```

then the rendered page includes the `<` and `>` characters as if they were HTML-encoded, so the output is bogus.

I can't, of course, call `HtmlHelper.Raw(string s)`, partly because I wouldn't know how to create an `HtmlHelper` from outside an MVC controller, and then because it returns an `IHtmlString` which isn't assignable to `string`.

If I call `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string s)`, the text is twice-encoded, and the rendered page shows `&lt;span class&eq;&quot;...`.

What should I do to have a string that renders to HTML in the view?

---

**EDIT**

Here's the code, from a `Helper` static class (all extension methods work, except they behave wrong):

```
public static string localize(string textId)
{
    string ret = "";

    // Query to obtain the localized string, 
    //   or to obtain a fallback in case there are issues 
    //   (missing localization, wrong id...)
    // In the end, ret is filled with the output string

#if !OFFICIAL
    ret = string.Format("<span class=\"localized\" title=\"{1}\">{0}</span>", ret, expression);
#endif

    return ret;
}

public static string localize(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, string expression)
{
    return trad(textId);
}
```

Comment: Where is your `string.Format` method called from?

Comment: `IHtmlString.ToString()` returns a `string`

Comment: @Lee, from inside the inner method, which may be called by the `HtmlHelper` extension method or from other places.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you're right, but I can't go through all the views of the project and change `@Html.localize("textId")` to `@Html.localize("textId").ToString()`...

Comment: If you have a `Html.Localize(string)` method, it is supposed to be used in a page. If you need to use such method somewhere else outside of a page, create another extension method, for example an extension method for `string` which returns localized string for you.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, that is exactly what my "inner" method does. Problems arise when I try to "enrich" this inner method with HTML tags.

Comment: Can you post your helper method and other related code? There's something definitely wrong somewhere else because your string formatting should be fine as it's used in html helpers all the time.

Comment: I think it's better to post a simple code to reproduce the problem and help us to better understand the question.

Comment: The problem is caused by the unlucky decision to put localization at the HTML level, and now you are trying to program your way out if it. The only real solution IMHO is to redesign this part of your solution, e.g. by creating a LocalizationHelper and then using it from HTML, not the other way round.

Comment: I've updated the question with my code.

Comment: @PeterB, if I understand what you say correctly (which I may not be doing), this is what I do already. I have a method that grabs the localization, then at HTML level I use the HtmlHelper to call that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you commented you want to make

```
@Html.localize("textId")
```

output an HTML element, the solution seems obvious: with a return type of `string` that's plain impossible by design. So change your method to not return `string`.

You already found you could in principle use `HtmlHelper.Raw` which returns `IHtmlString`, except that `IHtmlString` isn't assignable to `string`. If you change your return type to `IHtmlString`, problem solved.

Comment: True, but there is still one point. Some of my localized strings have placeholders because they should be passed to `string.Format()`. `string.Format()` of course accepts only strings, not `IHtmlString`s, and if I return an `IHtmlString` then call `ToString()` then the benefit is lost, so I end up with some text strings still showing up as if they were encoded. Suggestions for that?

Comment: @Simone I don't think that can be fit in the design you have now. You need to re-think your design. But if you now have `@string.Format(Html.localize("textId"), "param1", "param2")`, you should be able to change that without too much effort to `@Html.localize("textId", "param1", "param2")`, where you let `Html.localize` call `string.Format` before stuffing the result a `<span>` element.

Comment: Good suggestion @hvd, I hoped I could avoid it, but I guess I'll have to live with that. I'm trying that right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create your methods this way:

- The non-helper `Localize` method should only try to return localized `string`. Adding html tags is not concern of this method. (You can add html tags also here without any problem because in the next method, we use `HtmlString` to create output.)
- The helper method, should use previous method and then add html tags you need and at last return an [`HtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx).

**Code:**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Localize(string exp)
    {
        var ret = exp;
        try
        {
            //try to apply localized version of exp, for example:
            ret = exp + "_Localized";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 
            //Log ex
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static IHtmlString Localize(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, string exp)
    {
        var ret = string.Format("<span class=\"localized\" title=\"{0}\">{1}</span>",
                                exp, Localize(exp));
        return new HtmlString(ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would solve some problems, but it's not what I need, because 
1) I need the span exactly to track things gone wrong during the localization, which the helper's `Localize` knows nothing about, and
2) this would not keep track of _all_ the localizations I do. If I call the method from a controller (not via the helper), then no extra action is taken.

Comment: No problem, you can put html back to non-helper, it is just a recommendation about separation of concerns. It would work as expected because I use `HtmlString` as output.

Comment: True, but there is still one point. Some of my localized strings have placeholders because they should be passed to `string.Format()`. `string.Format()` of course accepts only strings, not `IHtmlString`s, and if I return an `IHtmlString` then call `ToString()` then the benefit is lost, so I end up with some text strings still showing up as if they were encoded. Suggestions for that?

Comment: You should copy and run and test the code to detect how it works. For example to test, in the first method use `ret = exp + "<a href=''>Link</a>";` and see the result. Or use for example `@Html.Localize("<a href=''>Link</a>")` you will see the result of method.

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm already testing it. I have the helper's method return an `IHtmlString`, but then when I pass it to `string.Format()` the problem is back. Full call:
`string.Format( Html.Localize("textId").ToString(), param1, param2 )`

Comment: Surely it works. `@{
    var a = new HtmlString(string.Format(Html.Localize("<a href=''>{0}</a>").ToHtmlString(), "Hi"));  
}` then 
`@a`

Comment: It works *if* I wrap the result of `string.Format()` in another `HtmlString`, which I can't do because I would have to change all instances project-wide.

Comment: No problem, choosing the best solution up to you. It seems you marked a similar answer as accepted. You should know while you can accept only one answer, but you can vote as many answer as you find helpful, including the accepted one :). It's not compulsory at all, but it's reasonable and recommended.

Comment: In fact the last specification I talked about wasn't described in the OP. I shall then upvote you :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, you also have my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Razor render `string` as is. You should use `HtmlString` for extension methods with markup.

If you declare your method as follows:

```
public static HtmlString localize(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, string expression)
{
    return new HtmlString(trad(textId));
}
```

You wiil be able to use your own extension method like

```
@Html.localize('your string')
```

which will be rendered as correct markup

Comment: True, but there is still one point. Some of my localized strings have placeholders because they should be passed to `string.Format()`. `string.Format()` of course accepts only strings, not `IHtmlString`s, and if I return an `IHtmlString` then call `ToString()` then the benefit is lost, so I end up with some text strings still showing up as if they were encoded. Suggestions for that?